# Eureka service deployed on PCF de-registers itself automatically after a few hours

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix, pcf

We are deploying the service on PCF(Pivotal cloud Foundry) and to register the service on the PCF service registry, we are using the Eureka service annotations. 
I am listing below the select few libraries that we are using in the context of eureka.

```
compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka")
compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server") 
compile("io.pivotal.spring.cloud:spring-cloud-services-starter-service-registry") 
compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context")
compile("io.pivotal.spring.cloud:spring-cloud-services-starter-config-client")
```

The issue we are facing is that the eureka service automatically deregisters/disappears from the service registry deployed on PCF after a few hours. 
We have tried to change the configuration settings in application.properties but nothing seems to working.
Any pointers to solve this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the SCS tile on PCF?

Comment: Nope we are deploying it using cf push.